# Help me polish my jQuery fade animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, fadein

Ok guys I have a series of 7 images that the rest fade to the background image when you roll over the selected one. i'm getting an odd strobe effect with the fade in/fade out on the hover. any idea on how to get the effect that when you move from one to the other just the now unselected one fades out and the selected one fades in? here's my code...

```
$('img','.p_div').hover(function(e){
$('img','.p_div').stop(true,true).not(this).fadeOut();  
},function(e){
$('img','.p_div').stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
});
```

and here's the site...

http://creativerxawards.com/dudnyk/people/

Comment: What worked for me...
   

     $('.m_img').mouseenter( 
          function(e){
           $('.m_img').not(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.01);  
        });
        $('.m_img').mouseleave( 
          function(e){
           $('.m_img').not(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1.0);  
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img','.p_div').hover( 
  function(e){
   $('img','.p_div').not(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();  
  },
  function(e){
   $('img','.p_div').fadeIn(); 
});
```

Comment: they're still doing the same effect. I added the code, have a look at the same link.

Comment: that is because you are `fading in` all the `div` and `img` on `mouseleave`

Comment: just checked and i think its fixed? you can answer your own question if that is the case